# Getting the following error from SQL Code: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. Not missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
   CustomerID CHAR(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   CustPhone CHAR(9), 
   CustName CHAR(20), 
   SpecialistID CHAR(2) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE CUSTOMER_SPECIALIST(SpecialistID)
);
```

I am getting the following output error from my code "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis".

Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **not** use the `CHAR` datatype. Use `varchar2` instead

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `FOREIGN KEY` keywords in an inline constraint and it is `REFERENCES` not `REFERENCE`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
   CustomerID CHAR(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   CustPhone CHAR(9), 
   CustName CHAR(20), 
   SpecialistID CHAR(2) REFERENCES CUSTOMER_SPECIALIST(SpecialistID)
);
```

However, I would name the table using the plural `CUSTOMERS` (rather than the singular, since it will contain many customers rather than one) and would not include the table name in the column names and would also name the constraints:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
   ID           CHAR(4)
                CONSTRAINT Customer__ID__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT Customer__ID__PK PRIMARY KEY, 
   Phone        CHAR(9), 
   Name         CHAR(20), 
   SpecialistID CHAR(2)
                CONSTRAINT Customer__SpecialistID__FK
                  REFERENCES CUSTOMER_SPECIALIST(SpecialistID)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b63a467eb838aa9212109fef211d873)

Comment: In addition to @MTO comments about style and naming conventions, I'd add to forget the MixedCaseNames when working with oracle.  Because of the way Oracle treats case-sensitive vs case-INsensitive names, the approach in oracle is to use an underscore, so instead of MixedCasteNames, it would be mixed_case_names.  I don't have room in a comment to fully explain it.  Just take off your Microsoft goggles, and "when in Rome (oracle) do as the Romans (oracleites?)"

Comment: The table name is the name of the entity. And that's singular, so `customer` is perfectly fine.